# How to create merged input (stdin) for a program

Tags: bash, stdin

Consider such script:

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
```

It will produce 3 lines and now I can run it like this:

```
abc_script | real_program
```

`real_program` will get in its input those 3 files. However, there is a problem for a user, instead of just calling `abc_script`, she/he has to remember to redirect the output to the `real_program`.

So how to move this redirection to the script? Something like this (the script):

```
echo a | echo b | echo c | real_program
```

This does not work, it is only an illustration what I would like to do -- hide calling of `real_program` inside the script.

---

*For the record: in my case the input consists of some file, additional extra lines. So I have:*

```
cat $input_file
echo $extra_line
```

*Not just a,b,c.*

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
( echo a
  echo b
  echo c ) | real_program
```

That runs the three `echo` commands in a subshell and pipes the subshell's output to the script.

Subshells are syntactical sugar for `bash -c 'echo a; echo b; echo c' | real_program`.

Comment: I see, they are merged and executed as one, instead of sequentially. Thank you very much for this! *For further readers, it can be put in one line, separated by semicolon.*

Comment: I have added a bit to my answer to show how the shell performs that operation.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this would be

```
echo -e "$(cat $input_file)\n$extra_line" | real_program
```

Answer (score 2):

A third way, which works at least with GNU bash 4.2.37 and should work with any recent bash and possibly other shells (I don't know how generally supported `<()` is), is to redirect input from a command.

```
$ echo hello > test
$ echo my > test
$ echo beautiful > test
$ cat <(cat test; echo world)
hello
my
beautiful
world
$
```

The idea is to first create the file, then launch `cat` redirecting its stdin from the output of the command sequence `cat test; echo world`. As seen in the output, that input becomes the concatenation of the output of all the input redirection commands.

An alternative way to express the same thing, which might be more portable, is to simply rewrite it as a plain old subshell pipe into a command:

```
(cat test; echo world) | cat
```

Note that the commands are executed sequentially, but their output becomes a single stream on the outer or next command's input. So while the outer `cat` in the above example sees no EOF or anything like that, if invoking the inner commands is expensive in some way, you will pay that price multiple times. I doubt there's any way around that.